# Find duplicates values in the linked list (Simple convert into difficult)

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, traversal

This seems to be a very simple question. I had been asked by the interviewer to find the duplicate element in the linked list, and then he told me Some of the constraints that made the question difficult for me. the constraint is you have to traverse the linked list only one time.

**Resources**

The only resource I have available is another linked list.

**BONUS**

Remove that Element if you can traverse it only one time,

The time should be O(N)

Q1: I can't find the Answer, I don't know if the solution exists or not or he was just confusing me... if yes, how can that be possible?

Comment: So there's only one duplicate element in the linked list?

Comment: there might be one or more...

Comment: @nakiya did you get my question

Comment: yes, Unfortunately I can't think of an O(n) algorithm for this case.

Comment: list is sorted or unsorted?

Comment: list is unsorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `HashMap`, If this were to be implemented in Java we could use [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) datastructure
The Map stores Key-Value Pairs and the elements can be accessed almost `O(1)`, therefore this snippet runs in `O(n)`

```
private void removeDuplicates(final Node node) {
     Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

     Node n = node;
     Node prev = null;
     while (n != null) {
         if (map.get(n.data) == null) {
             map.put(n.data, true);
         }
         else {
             System.out.println("Found Duplicate of: "+n.data);

             /*To remove duplicates. do this
             if (n.next != null) {
                 n.data = n.next.data;
                 n.next = n.next.next;
                 continue;
             }
             if (prev != null) {
                 prev.next = n.next;
             }
             */
        }
        prev = n;
        n = n.next;
    } 

}
```

Comment: this seems to be good.. but the in Big O(n) but the resources is the list,is there is no solution with the List....???

Comment: @Malik I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly, are you asking if we can do it without the map?

Comment: Yes, if we can do it with out the Map?

Comment: @Malik I dont think we can do it without a map, if the type of the data is known prior to doing this, say, if the data were known be to small letters of the alphabet we could use a boolean array of size 26 instead

Comment: @Malik If you are using other languages which dont have Maps, you should write a map on your own, read about how maps work

Comment: @Malik since you are asking to create an array you would have to know the maximum integer in the list,  and create a boolean array of that size which would consume a lot of memory if the max happens to be big, if you ask me a better way would be to use a map which you can write by implementing a good hashing function